# Non Javascript Map API Service

Tags: javascript, api, maps

Is there a way to prevent users from not having access to co-ordinates on a map through Javascript. All of the map services that I have seen use Javascript for the API but the problem is, I don't want to expose the co-ordinates to the users in case someone decides to steal them. Is there a map service that doesn't use Javascript for API?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try [Google Maps Image APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/imageapis/index.html), specifically the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html)

Comment: I have considered it but I feel it would be horrible user experience wise but you still have to add the location co-ordinates in the image tag. Thanks though.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to include coordinates. The Static Maps API also handles geocoding place names on the fly:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Locations
(see the section on addresses)

Other than that, what do you envision sending across to access the map center or map bounds?

Comment: Maybe POST via PHP? I don't think static maps would be good to use. The only reason I'm wondering about this is that it would be super easy for someone to just copy and rip the map off since it's Javascript. But it doesn't seem there's any other solution.